# Manage SP2010 user profiles as user profile administrator

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 event receiver that needs to update the user profile of another user on the site, ie not the user that triggered the event.  I attempt to open the UserProfileManager with the user token of a User Profile Admin (as suggested in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046363/allowing-userprofilemanager-permissions-in-sharepoint-2010)), but for some reason it is still running under the account of the person that triggered the event.
What is the correct way to impersonate a User Profile Service Application Administrator so I can edit any user's profile?

```
SPUserToken upmToken = web.AllUsers[@"domain\upadmin"].UserToken;//this user is a User Profile Service Application Administrator
using (SPSite upmSite = new SPSite(web.Url, upmToken))
{
    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(upmSite);
    UserProfileManager userProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(context, false);
    UserProfile userProfile = userProfileManager.GetUserProfile("anotheruser");
    userProfile["PictureUrl"].Value = pictureUrl;//System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation
    userProfile.Commit();
}
```

If I add myself to the User Profile Service Application Administrators, the code runs fine so it is obviously still trying to open the UserProfileManager under the account of the user that triggered the event receiver.
I do not believe it would be acceptable to add the app pool account to user profile administrators in order to use RunWithElevatedPermissions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the System Account token (SPUserToken.SystemAccount)?
using (SPSite mySiteSite = new SPSite(mySiteHostUrl, SPUserToken.SystemAccount))